# NSString to ByteArray and back

Tags: objective-c, character-encoding, nsstring

I am implementing an interface, which specifies `writeBytes()` and `readBytes()` on a file.

The data has to be transported as JSON.

For `readBytes` I do the following:

1. `NSFileHandle readDataOfLength`  - to read from a file
2. `NSString initWithData: encoding:` - to specify a given encoding
3. `NSString getBytes:buffer`
4. put each `buffer[i]` into a JSON array for transport : `[116,101,115,116]` for example `"test"` as UTF-8

On the other hand `writeBytes` should be doing about the same:

1. Parse the JSON array to a `NSArray`
2. `NSArray getObjects:buffer` - the conversion up to this point is successful
3. `NSString initWithBytes:buffer length: encoding:` - is not working, the return value is null
4. `NSData dataUsingEncoding:`
5. `NSFileHandle writeData`

Apparently `NSString initWithBytes` cannot handle buffers with content such as `[116,101,115,116]`. Is there any other way to convert a `NSString` into a byte array and back ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the NSUnicodeStringEncoding encoding ? If so, then you may have to prefix your bytes with a valid B.O.M (See [NSString reference](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring?language=objc), section "*Interpreting UTF-16-encoded data*").

Have you made a test with the NSASCIIStringEncoding to check that your code works for simple case ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you verified that the bytes within the array are a valid UTF-8 representation of a string? (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8)

If not, you'll get back nil:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int
main()
{
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    char ary[] = { 116, 101, 115, 116, 255 };

    NSString *s = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes: ary length: 5 encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    NSString *s2 = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes: ary length: 5 encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"s: %@, s2: %@", s, s2);

    [pool release];
}
```

When run, this prints:

```
2010-01-13 14:08:23.315 a.out[50653:903] s: testÃ¿, s2: (null)
```